# Undefined response when putting console.log and subscribing API service

Tags: angular

I am a beginner in Angular. I am trying to implement a login functionality in Angular 8. And here I am using back end REST API call to get the response. But when I am calling and checking the username and password process I am getting only a undefined response on console. And I checked that the back end API is working successfully.

My typescript code in logincontrol component is like the following:

```
onSubmit(user:any) 
  {
    console.log(this.user.username);

    this.logincontrolService.postCheckSurveyApplicationLoginApiMethod(this.user)
      .subscribe((data:any)=> this.userInstituteObj);

    console.log(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier);

    if(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier != null)
          {
            this.router.navigate(['home/homepage']);
          }
        else
          {
            alert('Please Enter Valid Username/Password..!!');
          }
  }
```

And my post method function inside service is like the following,

```
postCheckSurveyApplicationLoginApiMethod(user:any) 
{
    return this.http
      .post( this.baseurlService.getUrl()
            +this.portNumberService.getloginControlPortNumber()
            +this.instituteidentifierService.getInstitute()
            +'/security/checkSurevyApplicationLogin',
            this.user,
            {
              headers: this.applicationconfigService.getHeader()
            }
      );
}
```

When subscribing service, why am I getting undefined response here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL ,DR

do below changes :

```
onSubmit(user:any) 
  {
    console.log(this.user.username);

    this.logincontrolService.postCheckSurveyApplicationLoginApiMethod(this.user)
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{

           this.userInstituteObj = data;
           console.log(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier);

          if(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier != null)
          {
            this.router.navigate(['home/homepage']);
          }
        else
          {
            alert('Please Enter Valid Username/Password..!!');
          }

    } );


  }
```

why my code is not working ?

JS in asynchronous , it doesn't wait for any request to get complete. Since you are making a service call , JS will not wait for it to get complete and it will keep executing the next line of code . Since the next line is getting executed before the service returns the data , at this time `userInstituteObj` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes. I understood the mistake that I did here.Thank you for your guidance. I need one more clarification here. Depending on the result of parent ReST API call, If I need to call another microservice inside `if` , then Can I call there before the routing statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize:

```
this.logincontrolService.postCheckSurveyApplicationLoginApiMethod(this.user).subscribe(
       data => { this.userInstituteObj = data;

        console.log(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier);

    if(this.userInstituteObj.instituteIdentifier != null)
          {
            this.router.navigate(['home/homepage']);
          }
        else
          {
            alert('Please Enter Valid Username/Password..!!');
          }
     }
  }
```

when you called console.log the api have not return the response.